# php rand(5,15) gives 7771 but 7771 >15?

Tags: php, random, max, min

```
<?php
echo rand() . "\n";
echo rand() . "\n";

echo rand(5, 15);
?>
The above example will output something similar to:
7771
22264
11
```

in php **documentation** they say  *5 is the min*
*& 15 is the max*
& it will return a number between them

**but if it gave 7771 but 7771 >15 ??**

Comment: thak you am using it here
http://www.01tek.com/upload/index

Comment: -1 = You add arguments to the 3rd call and wonder why the first two don't stay within bounds. Seriously?!

Comment: just ate a lot of meat!?!?! WTF?

Answer (score 6):

You only specified 5,15 on one of the calls to rand(), the other two need it as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo rand() . "\n";
```

Outputs 7771

```
echo rand() . "\n";
```

Outputs 22264

```
echo rand(5, 15);
```

Outputs 11 which is between 5 and 15

Comment: Upvoted, as a reward for a more patient explanation than the asker deserved.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't restricted the first 2 calls. The third, which you have, resulted in 11, which *is* within the range.

Answer (score 0):

First Off, you will get a lot more respect if you only ask questions you know the answer to.  That probably explains the down votes.

Given that 5 should be the min and 15 the max your example

```
rand(5, 15)
// returns 11
```

Seems to be right.  But these

```
rand();
rand();
```

Seem to return something almost random?  :)  You are missing the "min" and "max" in those two.